# Apache 2.4 LDAP lookup sllow

Tags: apache-2.4, ldap

Server is running RHEL 7 and Apache 2.4.6; this is a pretty new (about a week old) problem. My department Intranet uses authentication against the university's Active Directory environment, and authentication for end-users takes over 30 seconds. Subsequent page loads are nearly-instant, and after some time (timeout, I assume), the problem is back.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/intranet>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted files"
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPBindDN CN=dept-binder,OU=Generic-Logon,OU=Generic,DC=example,DC=edu
  AuthLDAPBindPassword lamepassword
  AuthLDAPURL ldaps://ldap-ad.example.edu:636/dc=example,dc=edu?sAMAccountName?sub

  <RequireAny>
    require ldap-group CN=ug-dept-intranet,OU=Deoartment,OU=Dept-Groups,DC=example,DC=edu
  </RequireAny>
</Directory>
```

Here are some relevant lines from error_log:

```
AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 36 (server dept.example.edu:443)
AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group CN=ug-psy-employees,OU=Dynamic,OU=Psychology,OU=FSU-Dept-Groups,DC=fsu,DC=edu: denied (no authenticated user yet)
AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group CN=ug-dept-intranet,OU=Dept,OU=Dept-Groups,DC=example,DC=edu: denied (no authenticated user yet)
AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldaps://ldap-ad.example.edu:636/dc=example,dc=edu?sAMAccountName?sub
AH02001: Connection closed to child 11 with standard shutdown (server dept.example.edu:443)

# 37 seconds pass

AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting jsmith
AH01713: auth_ldap authorize: require group: testing for group membership in "CN=ug-dept-intranet,OU=Department,OU=Dept-Groups,DC=example,DC=edu"
AH01714: auth_ldap authorize: require group: testing for member: CN=jsmith,OU=PEOPLE,DC=example,DC=edu (CN=ug-dept-intranet,OU=Department,OU=Dept-Groups,DC=example,DC=edu)
AH01715: auth_ldap authorize: require group: authorization successful (attribute member) [Comparison true (adding to cache)][6 - Compare True]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had exactly the same problem on Fedora 33 with Apache 2.4 and I've solved it by adding:

`LDAPConnectionTimeout 1`

to the Apache global configuration:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ldap.html

The above parameter sets LDAP connection timeout to 1 second.
I'm using LDAPS with TLS and I suspect that delay was caused by Apache trying to resolve names or verify Active Directory/DC non-qualified (self enrolled) certificate.

Answer (score 0):

if your directory is large (university, so it could be), queries could be slow out of the box. You need to tweak them. No silver bullet, but some pointers:

- filter on indexed attributes
- try using the global catalog port if the attributes are listed as global catalog replicated
- avoid (if at allo possible) sub scoped searches. This is obviously not always possible, but it often is

There are more listed in this [Microsoft document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/what-makes-a-fast-query).

You can try [debugging mod_ldap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ldap.html#ldaplibrarydebug), maybe you can find some obvious problem that way, beware credentials could appear in the debug log.